# Split string with brace to become parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a input value "a[123],b[456],c[789]" and I want to return as "a=123&b=456&c789"

I've tried below code but no luck.. Is there a correct way to implement this?

```js
var str = "a[123],b[456],c[789]"
var string = (str).split(/\[|,|\]/);

alert(string);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is:

```
var rep = { '[': '=', ']': '', ',': '&' };
var query = str.replace(/[[,\]]/g, el => rep[el] );
```

Comment: Probably should use a character class there to be more efficient. `/[[,\]]/g`

Comment: thanks for your time sir @vohuman, I've tried your code and got "a=123],b[456],c[789]"

Comment: @mrrsb I had missed the `g` flag in the regex. Try the updated code please.

Comment: @Vohuman yah it only replaces the first instance. Very elegant solution I wish I code like this someday

Comment: @Desperado, likewise

Comment: @4castle this is more efficient, in your answer you added slice so this is an overhead  :)

Comment: @Desperado I agree. Just trying to make a great answer even better :)

Comment: @4castle That's a good alternative, also more readable. In this case it doesn't make a noticeable difference but I'll update the answer to use your regex.

Answer (score 1):

The delimiters are already there, it's just a matter of replacing one delimiter with another. Replace each `[` with an `=`, replace each `,` with an `&`, and remove all `]`.

```js
var str = "a[123],b[456],c[789]"
var string = str.replace(/([a-z])\[(\d+)],?/g, '$1=$2&').slice(0, -1);

alert(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Brute force way im not good at Regex. Just adding my thoughts

```js
 var str = "a[123],b[456],c[789]"
 str = str.replace(/],/g, '&');
 str = str.replace(/\[/g, '=');
 str = str.replace(/]/g,'');
 alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple 2 line answer for this is:

```
str=str.replace(/,/g,"&");
str=str.replace(/(\w)\[(\d+)\]/g,"$1=$2");
```